# Clarification on real-time networking game programming in Java

Tags: java, networking, real-time

I'm currently trying to redo my real-time game networking to get the bugs out, but I have some confusion over how networking works.

From what I've read, it is best to go with UDP when doing real-time, as packets that are old don't really matter anyways.  This is true for position, etc.  However, sensitive data like how much health someone has is necessary and I can't afford for that information to be lost.  How do people normally remedy this problem?

I've read of a method where clients will send in their action events to a server, which then processes all the commands and spits back out an updated game state to all the clients.  In this way, you can't lose any data because everyone will have the same simulation.  However, I'm wondering what this does to the clients' perceived "lag" - for example, if I send in a command to move left, then if the server needs time to process this, won't it seem to me that my command to move left got executed a short while after I commanded it?  Is there a way to fix this, or did I miss something?

Comment: In games where clients send their action events to a server, the clients time stamp the action events.  That way, the server can take client to server lag into account when calculating the position of players and mobs.  To do this properly, the server has to get the time from each of the clients when they connect, to keep the clients and server synchronized.

Comment: You say "when calculating the position..."  Does this mean that they project where they will move in the future?  I'm not sure I'm following =\

Comment: Yes, the server projects where the movable objects will be in the future.

Comment: But what if in between you issue another command?  Won't the outcome change?

Comment: There is no in between.  The server is calculating position based on its future, which is the client's present.  Don't forget, there's lag between the client and the server.  So when the client issues another command, the server won't see it for another 40 ms or so.

Comment: Ah this is so confusing T_T.  Okay if we use an example - say I want to move left.  I issue that command.  The server waits for other clients to issue their commands before sending out the updated game state.  If we look at my perspective, wouldn't we see me clicking the move left button, not moving, and then suddenly move a few milliseconds after?

Comment: Not quite.  You would continue to move forward then suddenly adjust to the left.  Stack Overflow is a question and answer site.  I can't tutor you here in the mechanics of client server games.

Comment: Yeah, I apologize for that.  Thanks for your responses though.

Comment: Pity that this is off-topic, perhaps migrate it to the proper SE site.